# How to set master detail selection list in a drop down menu in jdeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have oracle 11gr2 and JDeveloper 11.1.2.1.0.
I have 3 tables that are master detail detail. I want to use master detail single selection  in a drop-down menu  for these tables.
When I use these tables as adf table for master detail  it works correctly but when I use them as single selection list it doesnt work as it is supposed in a master detail manner! What am I missing here?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your master component set auto submit = true and master component set as partial trigger in child component 
eg: master component id =A and Child component id =B
A needs auto submit is true
B's partial trigger is A

Comment: tank you for your reply. is there any way to do this solution in popup? it work correctly  in jsf page but it was not work in popup.

Comment: This worked correctly for table control in popup. What is the component you used?

Answer (score 1):

Please add more details to your question. I amn't getting exactly what is your requirement. Did you mean to say dependent LOV or something..?

Comment: When i want to using tables for these master and details ,when select any row of master , it is automatically select child of  this master in detail .

Comment: but when i want to use single selection component , if you select any rows of master , none of details are filtered by master selection row . Is my question clear now ??

Comment: I guess, Autosubmit and partial trigger will take care of this. Try to do it in page if its not working, then do it in VO